# Calculate number of lines using XML attributes values

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have one xml file say like below,

```xml
<data>
     <fields>
          <artifacts>
              <artifact AL="68" CL="4" DL="0">
              </artifact>
              <artifact AL="86" CL="2" DL="1">
              </artifact>
              <artifact AL="34" CL="7" DL="0">
              </artifact>
              <artifact AL="18" CL="1" DL="3">
              </artifact>
          </artifacts>
          <dart>
              <bug>
                 <fields part="Major">Yes</fields>
                 <fields part="Major">Yes</fields>
                 <fields part="Major">No</fields>
              </bug>
          </dart>
     </fields>
</data>
```

I want PowerShell to read XML files and give the total lines (TL = AL + DL + CL) calculating each XML atrifact tags and list defects only "Major" equals Yes.

This is what I have tried:

```bsh
$xmlfile = Get-Content C:\Cdb\Cdb.xml
foreach($line in $xmlfile)
{
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content $line
    $linesadded = $xml.data.fields.artifacts.artifact | Select AL
    $lineschanged = $xml.data.fields.artifacts.artifact | Select CL
    $linesdeleted = $xml.data.fields.artifacts.artifact | Select AL
    $totalchangedlines = "$linesadded't$lineschanged't$linesdeleted";
    echo $totalchangedlines
    <#echo $linesadded#>
    $major = $xml.data.fields.dart.bug.fields
    $majnumber = 0;
    if ($major -eq "Yes")
    {
        $majnumber += [int]$major; 
    }
}
```

Result will come for below line if I use

```
PS> echo $linesadded
lines-added
-----------
68
86
34
18
```

but if I give `echo $totalchangedlines`, output is not coming corrcetly. Also it is better if comes in tabular column.

Comment: output should be separate TL and Defect count (on basis of Major)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not a script-writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please update the original question (using the [`edit` link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36355544/edit)), don't post code in the comments :)

Comment: Hi Jessen, thanks, i am newbie...i have updated what i have tried

Comment: here is a starting point `[xml]$xmlfile = Get-Content C:\Cdb\Cdb.xml` then you can navigate through that xml object.

Comment: another (easier) way to go about it: Import-Clixml ./file.xml
Then you can manage the contents like a psobject.

Comment: i have modified the script and redirect it to text file.. can i know, how to get sum of numbers inside the text file

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what you want to achieve in the end, but you definitely need to fix several things in the code you posted.

- First and foremost: lose the `foreach` loop. You do not want to process each line of an XML file individually. `[xml]$xml = Get-Content C:\Cdb\Cdb.xml` will read the entire file into one XML object.
- `$linesdeleted = $xml.data.fields.artifacts.artifact | Select AL`: that most likely should be `DL`.
- If you want each attribute in a separate list use `Select-Object -Expand` instead of just `Select-Object`. If you want the attributes of all artifacts in tabular form use `Select-Object AL, CL, DL` instead of selecting them into individual variables.
- `$major = $xml.data.fields.dart.bug.fields` produces a list of XML nodes. They will never equal a string `"Yes"`. Add `.#text` if you want a list of the values of the XML nodes, and change `-eq` to `-contains` if you want to check if that list contains a string `"Yes"`.

With that said, there are some things that require clarification:

- Do you want to accumulate the lines or just list them per artifact?
- What is casting `$major` to an integer and adding that to 0 supposed to achieve? Do you mean to increment `$majnumber`? In that case just use `$majnumber++`.
- Should the number be incremented if at least one major value is "Yes"? If all major values are "Yes"? Should it be incremented for each major value that is "Yes"?